# Trouble with scroll bar and slideToggle jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scrollbar, slidetoggle

I've got a problem with jQuery and IE9/IE10: I have a simple page with a list of tables (sometimes with many rows) and I'd like that if the user could hide the ones that he wants by a click.
So, I'd made that if the user clicks on the table's name, this last ones slides up.
It is something like this :

```
$(thisId + "title").bind('click', function() { 
     $(thisId + "span div:not(" + thisId + "title)").each(function() {
          $(this).slideToggle("medium");
     });
});
```

Everything works! The tables slide up and the content's height shrinks or grows if it has to. In FF, Chrome and Opera, I have no problem. 
In IE, the content shrinks or grows but the scrollbar's height doesn't change at all! So, the user can scroll all along the old content's height  (but there is nothing to show there anymore). In brief, IE keeps the old window's height.
If I reduce the window in the taskbar and call it back, then the height is right, like if the page was refreshed.

I tried to change the window's height by recomputing it each time that the user slides down or up one of the tables but I think this is a little bit messy and it doesn't seem to work on IE10.

I never have this problem before and it drives me crazy. Can anyone give me a hand? It will be much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I tried to hide every element on load then open them (I know which ones to open because I have to store this information in a database...). It worked fine... but now I have a horizontal scroll bar when I slide down one of the tables...

**EDIT 2:** I made something a little bit ugly that seems to work in IE9 but not in IE10. When the page is loaded, if one of the tables has to be hidden, I hide the scrollbar then show it again. So, the page's height is right.
Then, if the user decides to hide another table, I do the same thing and resize the window's height by doing this :

```
var newHeight = $(window).height() - $(this).height();
$(window).height(newHeight);
```

In IE, it seems that there's a "latency" problem like if there are too many things to do at once and so the scroll bar is not updated. No problem with the other browsers.

**EDIT 3:** So finally, I redid a test with .show() and hide.() and I added theses lines when a table is closed

```
var newWinHeight = $(window).height() - tempHeight;
$(window).height(newWinHeight);
$("body").css("overflow-y","hidden","important");
$("body").css("overflow-y","auto","important");
```

It worked in FF, Chrome, Opera and IE 9! But unfortunately not IE 10. It seems that IE needs to reload the "whole thing" to get the right values.

Comment: Does the same happen if you simply `show()` or `hide()` the table rows? Animating table rows with jquery can be problematic.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. It tried to use show() and hide() or .css("display","none") and the result is similar.
I don't understand why it doesn't work in IE because I have something similar on another page, but only for one div element, and everything is right.